# can't disable some services in msconfig of windows server 2003

Tags: windows-services, registry

I found services tab in msconfig. i have tried to disable the services (eg. rpc) in msconfig. but cannot disable the services. it says it is an essential. i also found one field in the same services tab as "essential". where this essential information is stored in registry?

Answer (score 0):

If a service is essential you should not disable it as it can lead to boot fail and some features of windows not working which could slow your computer down. Only do this if you are sure you know what your are doing. Follow this tutorial http://www.wikihow.com/Access-the-System-Configuration-Utility.